# Should I use Ruby 1.9x or 2.0x?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.0

I used to write some Python, and I know there are a lot of difference between Python 2.x and Python 3.x
Current now, I hope to use some Ruby to write a website (Maybe use Rails), but I am afraid that there will be the same problem in Ruby like Python.

Since I am a newcomer to Ruby, I just wonder what should I learn
Ruby 1.x or Ruby 2.x?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the major differences between Ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby 2.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799687/what-are-the-major-differences-between-ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-2-0-0)

Comment: As a beginner I would choose the newest version. And support for Ruby 1.9 will end February 23, 2015. The current version of Ruby is 2.1

Comment: Most of Ruby 2.x is backwards compatible with Ruby 1.9 series.  It's not like the relationship between python 2 and python 3.  This question isn't really a good fit for stack overflow, but in general you should use the most up to date version of a language you possibly can, barring the need to support older code that isn't compatible.  Right now, that would be the Ruby 2.1 series.

Comment: ..but that's not always the case, take for example perl 5 and perl 6, which are practically two different languages based on the same ideas and and, and, and... yeah this is totally opinion based and has no place on SO :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use ruby 2.1.1. The difference between Python 2 and 3 is so great that there are major backward compatibility issues. As this is not the case with ruby 1.9 vs 2.X you better start with the most current technology.